# FOR loops and range in Julia

Tags: julia

When I try to define range in a for loop when the range is less than 1 I get errors.

For example the following code:

```
i = linspace(0, 3, 200)
graph = zeros(length(i), 1)

for j in 0:0.015:3
    graph[j] = j*cos(j^2)
end
```

Reports the following error: `ERROR: BoundsError()`

Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do, but `j` starts at `0` which is not a valid index. The next value is `0.015` which is, of course, also not a valid index.

Comment: @Stefan What I wanted to do is to evaluate the function `f(x) = x*cos(x^2)` from 0 to 3. I wanted to save the results in a 200x1 array and then plot it using `PyPlot`. From what you said I understand that the `for` loops take only integer numbers. I guess I have to do something using `linspace`.

Comment: @Echetlaeus: FYI, I think your question doesn't reflect adequate effort (and as such could be downvoted). Have you googled what `BoundsError()` means and/or have read about for loops and range in Julia (or on other language) the problem would have been apparent.

Comment: @cd98 I agree with your statement. I have played a little bit with MATLAB and FORTRAN in the past in a basic level. This is my only programming experience.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like StefanKarpinski noted, it is not the for loop (variable) that only takes integers, but the array index. You cannot access the 0.15th element of an array.

How about this:

```
x = range(0, stop=3, length=200)
y = zeros(length(x))

for i = 1:length(x)
  j = x[i]
  y[i] = j*cos(j^2)
end
```

Or even:

```
x = range(0, stop=3, length=200)
y = zeros(length(x))

for (i, j) in enumerate(x)
  y[i] = j * cos(j * j)
end
```

Comment: @Oceanos: this would also work: `x = linspace(0, 3, 200); y = [j*cos(j^2) for j in x]`

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, the for loop takes more space without being clearer. Note sure what is considered "julianic", but in the python world I think most people would go for a list comprehension:

```
tic()
x = linspace(0, 3, 200)
y = [j*cos(j*j) for j in x]
toc()

elapsed time: 0.014455408 seconds
```

Even nicer to my eyes and faster is:

```
tic()
x = linspace(0, 3, 200)
y = x.*cos(x.^2)
toc()

elapsed time: 0.000600354 seconds
```

where the `.` in `.*` or `.^` indicates you're applying the method/function element by element.
Not sure why this is a faster. A Julia expert may want to help us in that.